# how can i pass code snippet as a multi lined string in json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postman

I am trying to create an editor where I send the code to the HackerEarth API for compilation in the form of JSON object.I am using PostMan to check the API. The JSON object is as follows :

```
{
"code":`#include<stdio.h>
        int main()
       {
         printf("hello world");
       }`,
"language":"C"
}
```

The error I got is as follows:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
 in JSON at position 29
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at parse (C:\Users\GURU\Documents\Project-master\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
at C:\Users\GURU\Documents\Project-master\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
at invokeCallback (C:\Users\GURU\Documents\Project-master\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
at done (C:\Users\GURU\Documents\Project-master\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\GURU\Documents\Project-master\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

Please Help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thats not JSON, but a JavaScript object. If you instead `JSON.stringify(obj)` then it becomes JSON. The mongodb tag is however a little worrying, since "what are you really trying to do?". Becuase MongoDB does not store "JSON strings" either. Plain JavaScript objects are parsed to BSON by the driver. No JSON here.

Answer (score 2):

You have mainly a bad use of JSON container.
Strings are always doublequoted.
Newline shoould be escaped. Doublequotes neeed to be escaped.

```
{
 "code":"#include <stdio.h> int main()  { printf(\"hello world\"); }", 
 "language":"C"
}
```

Use RFC 4627 for deeper knowledge or some JSON [validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Comment: I don't want it to be in a single line, I want to pass it to the API in the same way  @Stanislav Sokol

Comment: @gurucharan Your newlines will be encoded (probably as `\n`) and as this answer says - you must use double quotes for it to be valid. The backtick is not a valid string delimiter

Comment: I highly recoomend the [JSON](http://json.org/) read. It's clearly stated, that linebreaks are not allowed, so have to escape your linebreaks with `\n`